# Scala generics: How to declare that a type must be a case class?

Tags: scala, generics

I have several case classes with a `count` field. It's 1 by default, and I have a reduce in my code that groups duplicates and sums that value to find the number of each object. E.g.:

```
case class Person(name: String, count = 1)
personList.groupBy(_.name).reduce((x,y) => x.copy(count = x.count + 1))
```

I have this logic in several case classes, and since my logic is a bit more complicated than the example above I want to create a generic merging function.

So I've created a `sealed trait` with a `count` field. I've then changed my case classes to extend from this, e.g.:

```
case class Person(name: String, override val count) extends Countable
```

So far, so good.

However, I can't work out how to declare my `merge` function so that it only accepts case classes that extend `Countable`. Because of that, it can't find the `copy` method.

Here's what I have:

```
  def merge[T <: Countable](f: T => Seq[String])(ms: Seq[T]): Vector[T] = 
    ms.groupBy(x => f(x).mkString("_")).mapValues(_.reduce { (x,y) => 
     x.copy(count = x.count + 1)        // can't find `copy`
  }).values.toVector
```

Is there a typeclass that I can also include that means a type has a `copy` method (or is a case class) using Scala 2.11.7?

Update:

`Countable` trait is:

```
sealed trait Countable {

  def timesSeen: Long = 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you defined you Countable trait.
Following snippet works fine for me:

```
  trait Countable[Z] {
    def count: Int
    def copy: Z
  }

  case class Person(name: String, override val count: Int) extends Countable[Person] {
    override def copy: Person = this
  }

  def merge[T <: Countable[T]](f: T => Seq[String])(ms: Seq[T]): Vector[T] = {
    val r = ms.groupBy(x => f(x).mkString("_")).mapValues(_.reduce { (x, y) =>
      x.copy
    }).values.toVector
    r
  }
```

Comment: How are you declaring case classes that use that trait? I'm getting syntax errors.

Comment: It's not just `x.copy` it's `x.copy(count = x.count + 1)`. Now I can't parameterise `copy` at all...

Comment: Ah I think I've got it.

Comment: I have exactly the same question, how to define a copy() method in an abstract type that can be parameterized like the case class copy method, I am still not getting how to do that?