# Scala: force type parameter to be a case class

Tags: scala

I have an abstract class `Model` from which I create case classes:

```
abstract class Model
case class User(.) extends Model
```

an abstract class `Table` taking such a `Model` as type parameter, used in one of its default concrete methods:

```
abstract class Table[M <: Model] {
    def parser = SomeExternalBuilder[M]
}
```

The meaning is rather simple: "Give every instance of `Table` a default `parser` based on its own class".

The problem is that `SomeExternalBuilder` will only accept a *case class* as argument (*"case class expected: M"*), so it does not compile.

Can I make `Table` take only case classes as type parameter?

I have seen a few answers providing a missing `copy` method ([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417061/scala-generics-how-to-declare-that-a-type-must-be-a-case-class), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674602/can-a-scala-self-type-enforce-a-case-class-type)), so I tried this:

```
trait Model[T] {
    def copy: T
}

abstract class Table[M <: Model[M]]
```

but now case class `User` extends `Model[User]` and must overwrite `copy` too, every function creating a `Model` takes a type parameter, and honestly the code quickly starts being atrocious, all that for that single line in `Table`.

Is there no better way than copying that `def parser` line in every child's body?

**Edit**: N.B. The real function is `def parser: anorm.Macro.namedParser[M]` from the "anorm" library for Play.

**Edit**: Source of the type check by this macro: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/0a1b19055ba3e3749044ad8a54a6b2326235f7c8/core/src/main/scala/anorm/Macro.scala#L117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that SomeExternalBuilder will only accept a case class as argument ("case class expected: M"), so it does not compile.

I don't think you can ever get such a message from Scala compiler itself, which means that `SomeExternalBuilder.apply` is a macro. It requires a *specific* case class in order to know its fields, so that it doesn't matter if you could limit `M` to be a case class (which you can't): it still wouldn't accept a type parameter.

What you *can* do is create a macro annotation, so that when you write e.g.

```
@HasModel
class SomeTable extends Table[SomeModel] {
  ...
}
```

the `val parser = namedParser[SomeModel]` is generated automatically. 
Alternately, write `@HasModel[SomeModel] class SomeTable { ... }` and generate `extends Table[SomeModel]` as well.

It wouldn't be hard (as macros go), but you still need to annotate each class extending `Table`.

Comment: It actually asks for a user-defined case-class, and I found where it checks for it being a case class: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/0a1b19055ba3e3749044ad8a54a6b2326235f7c8/core/src/main/scala/anorm/Macro.scala#L117. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I've seen your comment on the other answer. This is exactly the situation my answer describes.

Comment: @JulienD I've added a possible alternative solution to your problem.

Comment: Since it is rather short, I prefer adding a one-line function definition than a macro call. But your answer is saying that what I want is not possible, which answers the question. Except I would love to know if there is just no such functionality ("limit M to be a case class") in Scala for the moment, or if it is impossible to do at all for theoretical reasons. So I could also accept this answer quietly knowing that nobody can bring more.

Comment: There is no such functionality at the moment, it could theoretically be added but I can't think of any case where it would be useful (as I mention, it wouldn't actually help in this case because just knowing `M` is a case class is not enough to generate a parser for it; you need to know which specific class it is).

Comment: I was thinking about forcing a type that would automatically have `this.typeSymbol.asClass.isCaseClass` and thus pass the macro's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Not fool proof solution but worth a try**

case classes extend Product and Serialisable. Constraint `Product with Serialisable` will help you get some type safety. `M` can be any class which extends Product with Serialisable. But Product is extended by case class mostly

```
abstract class Table[M <: (Product with Serializable)] { 
  def parser = SomeExternalBuilder[M]
}
```

Comment: This seems to be invalid syntax (*"identifier expected but '[' found."* on the second bracket). Also probable typo: `Serializable`.

Comment: @JulienD parenthesis added and type fixed

Comment: @JulienD fixed the compile error and edited the answer

Comment: Unfortunately same error: "case class expected: M". I have no idea how it is tested by `SomeExternalBuilder` for being a case class, that would help :( The real function is `anorm.Macro.namedParser[M]` from the anorm library for Play.

Comment: Note that this is a fairly loose approximation. For instance, any tuple type would satisfy the type bound.

Comment: Here is the check done by the real function, if it can help: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/0a1b19055ba3e3749044ad8a54a6b2326235f7c8/core/src/main/scala/anorm/Macro.scala#L117