# Enforce a Parameter is a case class

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to build a function that takes a generic case class, but I want to insure that the passed parameter is indeed a case class.

Searching has turned up only things about inheritance with self defined case classes but not about generic case classes. A guaranteed, messier, way of doing this is to use reflection to run a check on the passed `case class` object before `do things`. If it is not a case, throw an exception:

```
def handleCaseClass[A](caseClass:A):Unit = {
  val isCaseClass = // use reflection to check 
  if (isCaseClass) { /*do work */ } else { throw invalidArgumentException }
}
```

This could get a little messy, but not a big deal. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way by using type bounds, but I've searched around and can't find anything of the like:

```
def handleCaseClass[A <: ???](caseClass:A):Unit = {
        /* do work */
 }
```

Is anything like this possible? Also, what would be best practices?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a non-ugly way to do it. You could require `[A <: Product]` but then you allow tuples as well. Why do you want to restrict to case classes? This seems like it might be an XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417061/scala-generics-how-to-declare-that-a-type-must-be-a-case-class. The short answer is "there's no super-type for all case classes and only for them", but as Joe K said, the answer will depend on why you'd want to restrict to case classes.

Comment: @JoeK, Because I'm doing things that will need to iterate over the fields contained within the case class, both getting the actual field names and their values. However I'm trying to make this a library, so I'm trying to make this as generic as possible, so I don't have to restrict the case class at all. The Product may be enough of an enforcement.

Comment: @NateH06 class members always have names ... doesn't have to be a case class or a Product.

Comment: @NateH06, it sounds like you should check out the shapeless library, specifically the LabelledGeneric class. The type bound you want is actually probably just `[A : LabelledGeneric]`

Comment: Tuples are case classes; if you want to restrict to case classes, that includes tuples.